# Find glide reflection given composition of three reflections

Tags: geometry

Is there a simply procedure to solve this sort of question.

Find the line $d$ and the vector $u$ such that
$$
\sigma_{\ell} \sigma_{m} \sigma_{n}=\gamma_{d, \mathbf{u}}
$$
where $\ell, m, n$ are the lines $x=1, y=0,$ and $x+y=2$.

Note $\sigma$ is a reflection and $\gamma$ glide reflection.

Comment: Hi until someone with more experience sees the question, I can attempt it if you give me a formal matematical definition of "glide reflection"

Comment: Also please verify that $\sigma_\ell \sigma_m \sigma_n$ means reflect in $n$ first, then in $m$, then in $\ell$

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a much simpler way then my approach, but I will give you my answer for what is $\sigma_\ell \sigma_m \sigma_n$. From there you can see the glide reflection

---

We simply need to study each of the maps individually, which I will do **below**. The result is that given a point $(x,y)$ in the plane:
$$\begin{cases}
\sigma_\ell(x,y)=(2-x, y) \\
\sigma_m(x,y)= (x,-y) \\
\sigma_n(x,y)= (-y+2 , -x+2)
\end{cases}$$
therefore
$$ \sigma_\ell \sigma_m \sigma_n (x,y) = (y,x-2) $$

---

Firstly $\sigma_m$ is a reflection in the x-axis, so the y-coordinate simply flips
$$ \sigma_m (x,y) = (x,-y) .$$

To find $\sigma_\ell$ we will:

- Translate our picture left by 1 unit
- Reflect in the y-axis
- Translate our picture right by 1 unit

$$ (x,y) \to (x-1,y) \to (-(x-1),y) \to (-(x-1)+1,y) .$$
The operations result in
$$ \sigma_\ell (x,y) = (2-x, y)$$

To find $\sigma_n$ it is useful to draw pictures of the following steps:

- Translate our picture left by 2 units: add (-2,0)
- Rotate our picture by $\pi/4$: multiply on the left by
  $\begin{pmatrix} \cos (\pi/4) & -\sin (\pi/4) \\ \sin (\pi/4) & \cos (\pi/4) \end{pmatrix} = (1/\sqrt{2})\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
- Reflect in the x-axis: flip the second coordinate
- Rotate our picture back, by $-\pi/4$: multiply on the left by
  $\begin{pmatrix} \cos (-\pi/4) & -\sin (-\pi/4) \\ \sin (-\pi/4) & \cos (-\pi/4) \end{pmatrix} = (1/\sqrt{2})\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
- Translate our picture right by 2 units: add (2,0)

$$ (x,y) \to (x-2,0) \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x-2-y,x-2+y) \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x-2-y,2-x-y) \to (-y,-x+2) \to (-y+2, -x+2) $$
The operations result in
$$ \sigma_n (x,y) = (-y+2, -x+2)$$